# Intersection of a 45 degree angle and an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

If you are looking at the upper right quadrant of an ellipse centered at $(0,0)$, with $a=1$ and $b = 0.6$, and there is a $45$ degree line drawn from $(1, 0.6)$, how would I find the $(x,y)$ coordinate where the line crosses the ellipse? (I have been out of school for a long time, this is not homework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ellipse has the following equation:
$$
\frac{x^2}{1} + \frac{y^2}{0.6^2} = 1.
$$
Your line, which passes through $(1, 0.6)$ with $45$ angle has the following equation:
$$
y = x - 0.4.
$$
Now you need to solve the system of these two equations.
Substituting $y = x-0.4$ to the first equation, we get
$$
x^2 + \frac{x^2 - 0.8 x + 0.4^2}{0.6^2} = 1.
$$
Therefore, we obtain the following quadratic equation:
$$
(1+0.6^2) \, x^2 - 0.8 \,x - (0.6^2-0.4^2) = 0.
$$
Hence,
$$
1.36 x^2 - 0.8 x - 0.2 = 0.
$$
The roots of this quadratic equation will be (if I didn't make a mistake)
$$
x_1 = \frac{0.1 - \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34}, \quad 
x_2 = \frac{0.1 + \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34}.
$$
Thus, the points of intersection of line and ellipse will be
$$
\left(\frac{0.1 - \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34}, \frac{0.1 - \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34} - 0.4 \right) \\
\left(\frac{0.1 + \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34}, \frac{0.1 + \sqrt{0.027}}{0.34} - 0.4 \right) 
$$
The second point lies in the upper right quadrant.

Comment: Hi Voliar, thank you so much for answering.  Does the 0.8x come from 2ab?  I can solve down to 1.36x^2-.8x-.2=0, where do I go from there?  My math is very rusty.

Comment: The step I am missing is how do I turn 1.36x^2 - .8x -.2 = 0 into (x,y) coordinates that I can graph?  Thanks.

Comment: @beltran I edited my post, look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much Voliar.  You are very good at explaining things in a way I can understand.  If you don't mind, how do you do the roots, going from 1.36x^2 - .8x -.2 = 0 to the next step?

Comment: @beltran No problem. You just need to use the so-called Discriminant, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant)